# Data Studio date filter doesn't filter dates except in time series charts

Tags: looker-studio

I'm connecting to data in Data Studio using a connector to Snowflake. The date field is automatically recognized as a date. However, when adding a date range control, tables and scorecards are not filtered. Only time series like line graphs are filtered by the date range control.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might not have set the `Date Range Dimension` option on your table chart and that is the reason it might not be knowing which column to filter the data.

You can find the `Date range Dimension` option on the right side in the data tab under data source option.

You can set the `Date Range Dimension` value and then your output would start refreshing based on the date that you select in the date range control.

[image]

Comment: I have this set, but it still doesnt filter my pivot table data by the data, using the date selector control.

Comment: @BradyMoritz I don't know whether it works on pivoted data or not.

Comment: it seems to work on charts etc, but the pivot table it definitely is not. I did see a youtube video showing it working with a pivot though. and it would kinda make sense if it would right?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I used the Data Extract connector to create an extract of my data coming from Snowflake in Data Studio and for some reason that caused the date field to start to work in tables and scorecards when using the date range control to select specific dates.